# How to view user details in profile page using session in django?

Tags: django

I'm new in django,I need a help.How to view a person profile in template using django?.
I used `{{tablename.Username}}`to view the user name.It is working properly on the home page.But when i used the same to the view profile page to show all the fields it's not working.Please help !!

Comment: if its logged in user, then use `{{user.username}}`. Also share some code about what you have tried.

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: Welcome to SO, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask first, then edit your question so that others can understand.

Answer (score 3):

You can use {{ request.user.Username }} if user is logged in.

If the session is created then use as: {{ request.session.sessionName }}